# Count a occurrence of a specific word in a sentence haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new in Haskell and I'm tring to write a simple function that counts the number of occurences of a substring in a string.

For example : `"There is an apple"` and I want to count how many times `"is"` in the sentence, in this case the result should be `1`.

This is what I've tried:

```
countOf :: String -> Int
countOf x = length [n | n <- words x, filter "is" x]
```

According what I've studied it should work, but it doesn't. I really don't know how to solve the problem, and also don't know what the error message I get means:

```
input:1:41:
     Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[a0]'
     In the return type of a call of `filter'
     In the expression: filter "a" x
     In a stmt of a list comprehension: filter "a" x
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `filter` has the type

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

This means that its first argument is another *function*, which takes an element and returns a `Bool`, and it applies this function to each element of the second argument.  You're giving a `String` as the first argument instead of a function.  Maybe you want something more like

```
countOf x = length [n | n <- words x, filter (\w -> w == "is") x]
```

But this won't work either!  This is because any extra expression in a list comprehension has to be a `Bool`, not a list.  `filter` returns a list of elements, not a `Bool`, and this is actually the source of your compiler error, it expects a `Bool` but it sees a list of type `[a0]` (it hasn't even gotten far enough to realize it should be `[String]`).

Instead, you could do

```
countOf x = length [n | n <- words x, n == "is"]
```

And this would be equivalent to

```
countOf x = length (filter (\w -> w == "is") (words x))
```

Or with `$`:

```
countOf x = length $ filter (\w -> w == "is") $ words x
```

Haskell will actually let us simplify this even further to

```
countOf x = length $ filter (== "is") $ words x
```

Which uses what is known as an operator section.  You can then make it completely point free as

```
countOf = length . filter (== "is") . words
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. May i ask to your advice where can i read more about what this expresions  "filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]"  mean, and any other stuff where i can study haskell.I find some tutorial on the internet, but they aren't useful.

Comment: @Syngularity Have you checked out [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)?  That's the tutorial that really got me started.  After that I'd recommend the Real World Haskell book, which is also available online for free.  There's also a lot of good tutorials on the [School of Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school).

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
countOf :: String -> Int
countOf x = length [n | n <- words x, compare "is" n == EQ]
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci> countOf "There is an apple"
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the comparison straight in the comprehension:

```
countOf x = length [n | n <- words x, n == "is"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you try to count the number of occurences of a *word* in a string. In case you look for a substring:

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

countOf = length . filter (=="is") . conSubsequences
  where
    conSubsequences = concatMap inits . tails
```

Answer (score 0):

One could also try a foldr:

```
countOf :: String -> Int
countOf x = foldr count 0 (words x) 
  where 
  count x acc = if x == "is" then acc + 1 else acc
```